# Controlling input for Google TTS API

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, media-player, google-api

I'm creating a TTS app using google's unofficial tts api and it works fine but the api can only process a maximum of 100 characters at a time but my application may have to send strings containing as many as 300 characters.

Here is my code

```
        try {
        String text = "bonjour comment allez-vous faire";

        text=text.replace(" ", "%20"); 
        String oLanguage="fr";

        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);           
        player.setDataSource("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=" + oLanguage + "&q=" + text);

        player.prepare();
        player.start(); 

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

So my questions are

1. How do I get it to check the number of characters in the string and send only complete words within the 100 character limit.
2. How do I detect when the first group of TTS is finished so I can send the second to avoid both speech overlapping each other
3. Is there any need for me to use Asynctask for this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.How do I get it to check the number of characters in the string and send only complete words within the 100 character limit.**

```
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    int counter = 0;
    String textToSpeach = "Your long text";
    if(textToSpeach.length()>100)
    {   
        for(int i =0 ; i<(textToSpeach.length()/100)+1;i++)
        {
        String temp = textToSpeach.substring(0+counter,99+counter);
        arr.add(temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" ")));
        counter = counter + 100;
        }
    }
```

**2.How do I detect when the first group of TTS is finished so I can send the second to avoid both speech overlapping each other**

```
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            // pass next block
        }
    });
```

**3.Is there any need for me to use Asynctask for this process?**

Right now I dont see any need for that.

Comment: Finished testing the first part and it works but I would need to start the counter from the next character after temp.lastIndexOf(" ") for the second time so no characters are lost. How can I do this?

Comment: Counter variable should be declared at activity level..and static

Comment: The counter restarts from 100 in the code but what I'm asking is if the first string of 100 characters ends with eg: "have a nice da" instead of "have a nice day" the function lastindexof stops at "have a nice" the first time. Then I would like to restart the next string from "day".

Comment: I'm trying to use string.replace("first set of xters", ""); to edit the original string so only the words which get spoken are removed. It sounds like a good theory but it's not yet working

Comment: I got it working 

if (mainText.length() > (100)) {
     String temp = mainText.substring(0, 99);
     spokenText = temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" "));
     mainText = mainText.replace(spokenText, "");
    } else {
     spokenText = mainText.substring(0);
    }

But you were right for the initial question I asked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple: this is not a public API, don't use it. Use Andorid's built-in TTS engine for speech synthesis. It does not have string length limitations.

Comment: This sounds way better than the built-in TTS speech engine

Comment: Maybe, but Android TTS engines are extendable: if you need better sound, you can simply install a package that provides better sound. The unofficial API might disappear at any time, or you could be blocked if you issue too many requests. Not to mention that using it is legally gray (at least).

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be safe in the long run. Can you give me a link about these packages for better sound and can I embed them in my app or do you need to install them separately on your phone

Comment: There are lots of engines in the Play Store/Market, this on of the more famous/good ones. Find one that works for you and prompt users to install it on first run. You cannot embed it in the app though, it's a system service plugin. SVOX: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.svox.classic.langpack.fr_fr_fem